# SSIS Incremental without PK

Tags: ssis, increment

I am trying to build a package which is inserting/updating new rows to a table.
Here is the workflow :

[image: Merge package]

I have an auto incremental Id column as PK that cannot be used to link records.
Here is the content of my merge join :

[image: Merge Join]

My records are each time splitted into the New-Add section, even if it already exists, here is the conditional split definition :

```
(!ISNULL(View_Name_SRC) && ISNULL(View_Name_DST)) && (!ISNULL(Hostname_SRC) && ISNULL(Hostname_DST)) && (!ISNULL(DB_Name_SRC) && ISNULL(DB_Name_DST)) && (!ISNULL(Site_SRC) && ISNULL(Site_DST)) && (!ISNULL(Owner_SRC) && ISNULL(Owner_DST))
```

The SRC & DST are different DB with exactly the same structure.
Here are the Conditional split conditions :
[image]

The Goal is to recognize new record to add it, existing to update the TimeStamp and Deleted to update the Rev Field that flag is still used or not.
I cannot find why it is still a new record even if already into DB, maybe there is a better approach for this ? Is there an error in my condition ?
Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think we have enough visibility into your package to help you.  Where are these coming from?  `View_Name_SRC`, `View_Name_DST`, etc?   Please add a screenshot of the entire Conditional Split.

Comment: Use Change Tracking to find changed rows, even deleted ones. It works on all editions